# colordepth won't be set to 8 on an intel HD chipset

Tags: xorg, 16.04, mate

I have a laptop from 2012. average graphics- intel i5-520M with its appropriate intelHD graphics- and I have a bizzarre compulsion to view it in greyscale.

Trying to set the colourdepth in xorg to 8, however, makes the login screen disappear completely (However, it is still there, and I can login), and, when I finally have fumbled for the login box and login to desktop, discover that I cannot see the text unless I really concentrate! the background image only shows a portion, the icons are either black boxes or greyscale boxes, and I immediately switch to colour again.

My question is, is there a way to make it greyscale and just see the icons and text as greyscale versions? I'd prefer it if It can make the whole thing functionally greyscale, and not just the windows.

Answer (score 0):

LightDM does not work with a colourdepth of 8. get GDM or other managers.

As for the weird icons, change it from "pseudoColor" or "GrayScale" to "StaticGrey"